# Not able to show the parsed data on a secondary screen

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using an example found online from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1clUga356ms) to understand how to parse an XML file in an app.
I used the same employees.xml file and copied the code as it is, with the differnce that I don't use the main screen of the app, but a secondary you open with a menu Button.
I replaced the MainActivity's etc with the Activity (PlacesActivity) I currently use, but I don't get anything shown on the screen.

The code files are shown below.

Have I done something wrong? Could you please help?

PlacesActivity.java

```
public class PlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    List<Employee> employees = null;

    try{
        XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
        employees = parser.parse(getAssets().open("employees.xml"));
        ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(this, R.layout.list_item, employees);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int id;
private String department;
private String type;
private String email;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return id + ": " + name + "\n" + department + "-" + type + "\n" + email;
}}
```

XMLPullParserHandler.java

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {

List<Employee> employees;

private Employee employee;
private String text;

public XMLPullParserHandler(){
    employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public List<Employee> parse(InputStream is){

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;

    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")){
                        employee = new Employee();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                    if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("employee")){
                        employees.add(employee);
                    }else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
                        employee.setName(text);
                    }else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                        employee.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));
                    }else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("department")){
                        employee.setDepartment(text);
                    }else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("email")){
                        employee.setEmail(text);
                    }else if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("type")){
                        employee.setType(text);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employees;
}}
```

activity_places.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Employees:" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView></LinearLayout>
```

content_places.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.media1.thesistest2.PlacesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_places">

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16dp">

</TextView>
```

employees.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<employees>

<employee>
    <id>2165</id>
    <name>Mike</name>
    <department>Dev</department>
    <type>Perm</type>
    <email>mike@a.com</email>
</employee>

<employee>
    <id>3463</id>
    <name>Trav</name>
    <department>DB</department>
    <type>Contr</type>
    <email>travis@a.com</email>
</employee>

<employee>
    <id>2001</id>
    <name>Mary</name>
    <department>Test</department>
    <type>Perm</type>
    <email>mary@a.com</email>
</employee>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misplaced the employees.xml file. The assets directory had to be created under src/main of the project, and there I should have placed my xml file that I wanted to parse. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no data is getting set into the TextView of your Adapter.

You should be able to verify that with this

```
try {
    XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
    employees = parser.parse(getAssets().open("employees.xml"));

    Log.d("num employees", "" + employees.size()); // Check the Logcat!

    ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = ...
```

---

You have a few options

1) Use the default item layout

```
ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        employees);
```

2) Use your layout but add an ID of `android:id/text1` into your `item_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"       <!--- See here --->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16dp" />
```

3) Use your own ID value, but set it within the `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Employee>(
        this, 
        R.layout.list_item, 
        R.id.item_title,   // for example
        employees);
```

4) Define your own `EmployeeAdapter` class that extends `ArrayAdapter<Employee>`

Comment: I used the first option but still nothing shows up.. Could it be something else that has gone wrong?

Comment: Did you verify the list has data via the Logcat?

Comment: It does seem strange you have `android:layout_weight` but no use of a `layout_weightSum`

Comment: I tried adding a weightSum but still nothing is showing. Its an example from the internet so I got it exactly how it was. I thought maybe I was doing something wrong in the process of showing it in another screen than the main. Because it seems to work for the creator of the example.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's because you're not defining a namespace in your employees.xml but you have `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Try this: `factory.setNamespaceAware(false);`

Comment: Is your List with employees filled?

Comment: you mean the employees.xml file? Yes it has 3 employees.

Comment: No, I mean the `List<Employee>`